# What does $0 < x \leq y \leq z$ geometrically describe (as a region in $\mathbb{R}^3$)?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

Let $(x,y,z)$ denote the coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^3$. I am attempting to determine the geometry of the region described by $$0 < x \leq y \leq z.$$ Of course, the projection to each copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is clearly the set of points which lie above the boundary line $y=x$. This happens for along each pair of axes $(x,y)$, $(x,z)$, and $(y,z)$. I can't visualise, however, the resulting region in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: It's a pyramidal cone that takes up $1/6$ of the nonnegative orthant $[0, \infty)^3$. If you set some of the inequalities to equalities, you'll get the faces and edges of this cone.

Comment: This might be described as $x-z \leq 0$, $y-z \leq 0$ and $x>0.$ That is a intersection of three half-spaces. One open and two closed spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fixing values for $z$ and visualizing the shape of the resulting region in the $z=\text{constant}$ plane. For example, the intersection of your region with the plane $z=0$ is a single point (edit: well, technically it's empty, since you set $x>0$), but in the plane $z=1$ we get a triangle, and $z=2$ a bigger triangle. Generalize. The end result is as the comments suggest: a triangular cone.